# Remove whitespace and multiple line from string?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have a string , like this:

```
"  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n      "
```

I want the result is:

```
"assddd\nadjffffdd\ntjhfhdf".
```

1: I used trimmingCharacters to remove the beginning and the ending:

```
let title = "  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

2: remove whitespaces

```
let result = title.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

but, how to keep the first "\n" between the character and remove other "\n" ？

Comment: `let result = title.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")`

Comment: You can use regular expresion for this

Comment: it will replace all of them , I want keep the first one.

Comment: I just want to keep the first \n between the character. So I posted my result was "assddd\nadjffffdd\ntjhfhdf".  Between the  "d" and "a" had a \n, the scond place is between "d" and "t".

Answer (score 7):

You can find two or more consecutive newline characters with
a regular expression, and replace them with a single newline
character. Example:

```
let s1 = "AA\n\nBB\nCC\n\n\n\n\nDD"
let s2 = s1.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n{2,}", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)

print(s1.debugDescription) // "AA\n\nBB\nCC\n\n\n\n\nDD"
print(s2.debugDescription) // "AA\nBB\nCC\nDD"
```

Applied to your case:

```
let title = "  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n      "

let result = title.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n{2,}", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)

print(result.debugDescription) // "assddd\nadjffffdd\ntjhfhdf"
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with your sample text, we can trim the ends:

```
let sample = "  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n      "
let trimmedEnds = sample.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

If you just want to remove space and compress newlines:

```
let noHorizSpace = trimmedEnds.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") // remove all spaces
let singleVertSpace = noHorizSpace.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n{2,}", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression) // squash runs of two or more newlines
```

or using a regular expression for the spaces:

```
let noHorizSpace = trimmedEnds.replacingOccurrences(of: " +", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
let singleVertSpace = noHorizSpace.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n{2,}", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)
```

But (for fun?) what about all Unicode horizontal (spaces, tabs, etc.) and vertical (newlines, form feeds, paragraph separators, etc.)? For that there are the RE patterns `\h` and `\v`:

```
let noHorizSpace = trimmedEnds.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\h+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
let singleVertSpace = noHorizSpace.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\v+", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)
```

You *can* solve this with a single regular expression, but it is better to heed the advice in [ICU RE User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) and use multiple simpler REs.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
let str = "  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n      "
print("str: \(str)")
let str2 = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
print("str2: \(str2)")
let lines = str2.components(separatedBy:"\n")
print("lines: \(lines)")
let linesFiltered = lines.filter({($0.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)).count > 0})
print("linesFiltered: \(linesFiltered)")
let linesTrimmed = linesFiltered.map({$0.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)})
print("linesTrimmed: \(linesTrimmed)")
let endStr = linesTrimmed.joined(separator: "\n")
print("endStr:\n\(endStr)")
print("endStr:\n\(endStr.debugDescription)")
```

The idea:
Remove all spaces because you don't want them.
Get all lines separated by a breakLine ("\n")
 Because you need to reassemble them with only one if repeated and put them in an array
Remove empty lines (wether it's only spaces and/or new lines)
Remove space/newlines before and after each line (trim)
Recompose the string

This output:

```
str:   
 assddd




 adjf fff dd 



       tjhfhdf 

str2: 
assddd




adjffffdd



tjhfhdf

lines: ["", "assddd", "", "", "", "", "adjffffdd", "", "", "", "tjhfhdf", ""]
linesFiltered: ["assddd", "adjffffdd", "tjhfhdf"]
linesTrimmed: ["assddd", "adjffffdd", "tjhfhdf"]
endStr:
assddd
adjffffdd
tjhfhdf
endStr:
"assddd\nadjffffdd\ntjhfhdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comments using a regular expresion you can do this,

```
func stringByAdjustingString(text:String) ->String{
    do{

    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\n+", options:[.dotMatchesLineSeparators])
    let resultString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: text, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count), withTemplate: "\n")

    return resultString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
    catch{
        return ""
    }
}
```

**input :** "  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n      "

**Output :** "assddd\nadjffffdd\ntjhfhdf"

Comment: Your last return will never be executed. `NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0)` ??? This looks so ugly, why not simply `[]`?  Btw that's the default value, so you can just omit the options parameter.

Comment: Btw instead of initialising a new NSString object just to get its length, you could just pass the String.UTF16View count `NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count)`. Note that this does exactly the same solution provided by MartinR but it also replaces unnecessarily the single occurrences of new lines

Comment: thanks @LeoDabus updated my answer with your comments recommendations

Answer (score 1):

```
    It should help you

   var str = "  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n      "
        str = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        //str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n")
        let array = str.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        var finalArray = [String]()
        for x in array {
            if !x.isEmpty  {
                finalArray.append(x)
            }
        }
        str = finalArray.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: `if x.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8) > 0` is a complicated way to check if a string is not empty ... there is a `isEmpty` method!

Comment: `CharacterSet` is redundant `trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)` and better to use newLines character set `components(separatedBy: .newLines)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var titleTrimmedLines = [String]()    
let title = "  \n assddd\n\n\n\n\n adjf fff dd \n\n\n\n       tjhfhdf \n      "
title(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).forEach { titleTrimmedLines.append($0.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)) }
let result = titleTrimmedLines.joined()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use for remove white spaces in string the following method

```
yourString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

or if you want delente white spaces and lines

```
yourString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

I hope it can be helpful!