# Remove new lines and keep maximum 2

Tags: swift, regex, string

I have a string like this

```
Why you should root for Argentina?

Hi



Why should you




It ends here
```

which in my code it looks like this:

let myString = "Why you should root for Argentina? \nHi \n\n\nWhy should you \n\n\n\nIt ends here"

and as you can see it has lot of new lines which is not what I want. I've tried trimming method to see if it helps me to remove and keep maximum 2 new lines

```
let newString = myString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

but it doesn't help me at all. Is there a way that I can limit the amount of new lines to 2 at most. My expected result should be

```
Why you should root for Argentina?

Hi 


Why should you


It ends here
```

which is equivalent to

```
newString = "Why you should root for Argentina? \nHi \n\nWhy should you \n\nIt ends here"
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: That's not what the `trimmingCharacters(in:)` method does, it only trims characters off the start/end. You could use a regex instead. Replace every `\n(\n)+` with just `\n`

Comment: See the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47796613/1226963. You just need to check for 3 or more newlines and replace it with two newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let result: String = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n{3,}", with: "\n\n", options: .regularExpression)
```